# HTML5 Canvas: Rendering aliased text

Tags: text, html5-canvas

When you render text on an HTML5 canvas (using the `fillText` command, for example), the text will render anti-aliased, meaning the text looks smoother.  The downside is that it becomes very noticable when trying to render small text or specifically non-aliased fonts (such as [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(typeface))).  Because of this, what I want to do is render text aliased, rather than anti-aliased.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no native way to turn off anti-aliasing for text.

The solution is to use the old-school approach of bitmap fonts, that is, in the case of HTML5 canvas a sprite-sheet where you copy each bitmap letter to the canvas. By using a sprite-sheet with transparent background you can easily change the color/gradient etc. of it as well.

An example of such bitmap:

[image: bitmap font sprite-sheet]

For it to work you need to know what characters it contains ("map"), the width and height of each character, and the width of the font bitmap.

Note: In most cases you'll probably end up with a mono-spaced font where all cells have the same size. You *can* use a proportional font but in that case you need to be aware of that you need to map each character with an absolute position and include the width and height as well for its cell.

### An example with comments:

```js
const ctx = c.getContext("2d"), font = new Image;
font.onload = () => {
  // define some meta-data
  const charWidth = 12;                          // character cell, in pixels
  const charHeight = 16;
  const sheetWidth = (font.width / charWidth)|0; // width, in characters, of the image itself

  // map so we can use index of a char. to calc. position in bitmap
  const charMap = " !\"#$% '()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~§";

  // Draw some demo text
  const timeStart = performance.now();
  fillBitmapText(font, "Demo text using bitmap font!", 20, 20);
  fillBitmapText(font, "This is line 2...", 20, 45);
  const timeEnd = performance.now();
  console.log("Text above rendered in", timeEnd - timeStart, "ms");
  
  // main example function
  function fillBitmapText(font, text, x, y) {
    // always make sure x and y are integer positions
    x = x|0;
    y = y|0;
    // current x position
    let cx = x;
    // now, iterate over text per char.
    for(let char of text) {
      // get index in map:
      const i = charMap.indexOf(char);
      if (i >= 0) { // valid char
        // Use index to calculate position in bitmap:
        const bx = (i % sheetWidth) * charWidth;
        const by = ((i / sheetWidth)|0) * charHeight;
        
        // draw in character on canvas
        ctx.drawImage(font, 
          // position and size from font bitmap
          bx, by, charWidth, charHeight,
          // position on canvas, same size
          cx, y, charWidth, charHeight);
      }
      cx += charWidth;  // increment current canvas x position
    }
  }
}
font.src = "//i.stack.imgur.com/GeawH.png";
```

```css
body {background:#fff}
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=640></canvas>
```

This should produce an output similar to this:

[image: demo output]

You can modify this to suit your needs. Notice that the bitmap used here is not transparent - I'll leave that to OP.